# Is it okay to use css classnames as an id for a module or widget?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I read an [interesting post](http://csswizardry.com/2013/05/hashed-classes-in-css/) on using a css classname instead of the id attribute for identifying modules or widgets. The css classname could be prefixed with a hash or underscore, to indicate that the classname is used as an id. The reason for this being, that ids can only be used once per webpage whereas a module or widget could appear multiple times.

**Simple Example**

Instead of using ids such as

```
<div id="currencyConverter1" class="foo">EUR/USD</div>
<div id="currencyConverter2" class="foo">GB/USD</div>
```

prefixed classnames are used

```
<div class="#currencyConverter foo">EUR/USD</div>
<div class="#currencyConverter foo">GB/USD</div>
```

In the [article](http://csswizardry.com/2013/05/hashed-classes-in-css/) it suggests, that an underscore could be used instead of a hash, because hashes need to be escaped.

I quite like this idea, but I'm not sure if this is good practice or has any drawbacks. What is the general opinion on this?

Comment: Seriously? Article says to avoid real IDs like the plague in CSS but goes promoting the use of faux IDs as class names, even so far as to suggest `#` just because it can be escaped to make valid CSS? Whether in context or out, that is just all sorts of ridiculous.

Comment: Just use classes. No need to pretend they're ids by giving them some made up prefix.

Comment: "The css classname could be prefixed with a hash or underscore, to indicate that the classname is used as an id" In what way is it being used as an `id`, if it's not an `id`? People do come up with some stupid ideas.

Comment: @TJ. Having now read the article in question, yup, it's stupid. The author himself says "I've no idea why you'd ever want to do this." Out of interest, what do you like about the idea? What would you be trying to achieve by using it?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite i disagree. It makes it visually clear that that class is a unique identifier

Comment: @Sprottenwels: classes *aren't* unique identifiers. IDs are unique identifiers. "Oh, but I've decided they are in my app!" Great. I've decided that the hedges in my garden are apple trees. Go and pick yourself an imaginary apple.

Comment: @Sprottenwels: The point here is that it's akin to using a table for layout. You're using something for the wrong purpose.

Comment: No need to get harsh :)
In the end, it's just a workaround. iF you've got a very unique element in your app, than why not give it a unique class and mark it as such. If later in the process more of those elements are needed, than it's not a problem. If you don#t like it, you have not to use it, but i wouldn't call it a 'stupid idea'

Comment: If I've got a very unique element in my app, I would give it an ID. Common sense. Also if the point of avoiding ID selectors is because it prevents reusability, how does making class names that essentially act like ID selectors minus the specificity remedy that?

Comment: I can vaguely see one reason to do this: you can't have more than one `id` on any element and it's perceivable that that would sometimes be useful.

Comment: How i said below, it depends on personal taste. However, i'd say that there is no disadvantage in that class approach. I further mentioned that there are a lot of folks who thought about this, maybe you could read through some of those articles sometimes

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: If you work with modules or widgets, basically anything that is reusable such as a currency converter, you cannot name it with an id. I've seen it happen often in a cms environment, where an id was used and the same id appears multiple times.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz: Yeah but that doesn't really provide an excuse for avoiding IDs in CSS like the plague yet embracing them in scripts.

Comment: Here is the original article he wrote about IDs: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/

Comment: @Sprottenwels: it's a workaround for an imaginary problem. There's no such thing as "very unique". "Unique" means "nothing else is the same". If it's unique, give it an `id`, because it's unique. If you're not sure it'll be unique, don't give it an id. If it's unique but you don't want to use the id selector in CSS due to its specificity, give it a class and use that. Why you'd need to add some custom junk onto the class name to indicate that it's used on a unique element is beyond me.

Comment: @TJ.: In that case don't use an ID, just use a regular class name as mentioned above. Naming a class like an ID just sets you up for hell, and for what purpose?

Comment: @Sprottenwels: "i'd say that there is no disadvantage in that class approach". It adds stuff to the class name without purpose. It makes it harder to discern the purpose of the code.

Comment: @Rob: So in other words he's either changed his view completely, or he's contradicting himself...?

Comment: The question was whether or not it would be okay to do this. In conclusion, i stay with "it is okay, do whatever you want if you can live with it". I'm outta here ;)

Comment: @BoltClock I struggle with what the heck he's trying to say.

Comment: @TJ.: sure, but why would you add a hash or an underscore or whatever to the start of the classname that you use for a module or widget like that? What meaning does that convey?

Comment: @BoltClock : I think there should be some convention for this. I'm saying I find the idea of using a prefix excellent, but I do sympathise with it. The id attribute is for naming and identification, but you cannot use it to name something that appears more than once.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : To indicate that it is a name of a module that can appear more than once.

Comment: @Rob: Oh, but of course he added this: **"N.B. Since authoring this article I have decided that a blanket ban is sensible. Save yourself many potential headaches and never use IDs in your CSS files."** Talk about a cop-out.

Comment: @TJ.: some convention for *what*? If something can appear on a page more than once, it gets a class. Simple. What different kind of thing is there that needs a class with a specific naming convention?

Comment: @TJ. how does a regular class not indicate that?

Comment: Overall, as mentioned, Harry Roberts finds problems using ID due to specificity issues he's found. I find myself agreeing with @BoltClock and PaulD.Waite here.

Comment: @Rob: I guess that’s what it boils down to. I don’t get how adding stuff to your class names is meant to help though. Just don’t use the ID selector.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite For example: Instead of `<div class="modulename skinname skinname">` the following is used `<div class="#modulename skinname skinname">` to mark the nameclass.

Comment: ...and it doesn't have to be a hash. I'm well aware of the (readability) issues this could cause.

Comment: @TJ. So the hash (or, as you say, whatever character) is indicating that the class is the name of a module. What's a module in this context? How does it make the CSS class different?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : I'm not trying to convince anyone this idea is good. I'm here to get the opinion of others. I'm a big fan of using common best practice and I view starting or creating anything new as a last resort. The context doesn't matter. I'm talking about using an identification multiple times and highlighting this identification.

Comment: @TJ. I know you're not. I'm trying to understand what the purpose of this convention would be. "I'm talking about using an identification multiple times and highlighting this identification." I don't understand what you mean by "identification" in that sentence. In your example, you seem to be drawing a distinction between a skin name and a module name. Are you saying that some of your classes describe what the HTML element *is* (module name), and some describe the name of a set of styles you're applying to the element (skin name)? And that the former is an "identification"?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : Your last two questions are part of the big question, bearing semantics in mind of course. A css class should not be connected with the style formatting (eg. .red-module). In his answer BoltClock uses my-module as a prefix. I'm using a similar convention now and it's the same as using a hash or underscore, except the latter is shorter, but agreed more confusing and less readable. It would also be great to know if there is a common practice for this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33364/discussion-between-paul-d-waite-and-tj)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't get simpler than this: **does it uniquely identify an element within a document tree now and forever? Use an ID. If not, use a class name.**

Remember that IDs and classes are properties pertaining to *each element*, not a group of elements collectively. Using "identifier" to mean "identifying a *group* of elements" is futile; that's why you have class names instead, to *classify* those elements as being related in some manner.

If you're "identifying" elements that are *members of a specific widget or module*, you have free reign to add a class name to each element representing that widget or module, and select it in addition to the element's class:

```
<div class="my-module foo">.my-module.foo</div>
<div class="my-module bar">.my-module.bar</div>
```

Or, if specificity is such a huge issue that you can't even afford to stack another class selector to your rules, prefix the element's class name with the name of that module and select it.

```
<div class="my-module-foo">.my-module-foo</div>
<div class="my-module-bar">.my-module-bar</div>
```

If that's the question, then yes, it's perfectly legitimate — as I've mentioned, that's the whole *point* of class names and selectors.

But there are no legitimate benefits to making a class selector "look like" an ID selector without functioning like one. What it does cause, on the other hand, is needless confusion, especially for other authors who may not know better. If you want to avoid ID selectors like the plague, *fine*, leave them alone; nobody's forcing you to use them. But if you want to *uniquely identify* singular elements, then you may want to remember that CSS already provides a feature for that to complement the `id` attribute in HTML, known as the [ID selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors). There's no need to hack other parts of the selector syntax to emulate some other feature that's already readily available to you and has been since [the very beginning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#id-as-selector).

Incidentally, if you're running into specificity issues with your CSS rules, then it's your CSS rules that need refactoring, not your markup. Hacking your markup to accommodate your style rules only leads to further trouble, at least in my experience. (I understand the irony in saying this given that hashes are allowed in identifiers starting with HTML5.)

Comment: Let this be the last time, if not the first, that I'm ever contributing to this debate. At least on Stack Overflow, until I finish my site and build myself a blog. Then maybe I'll take the time to write more extensively. And then I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I'll go with this since it makes sense and since I'm an advocate of readability without causing confusion. I can understand why this topic is tiring.

Comment: Yeah, I gotta get me one of them there blog things.

Comment: @Rob: I used to have one, but that was so long ago I'm not sure anything I wrote there is relevant anymore today. Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly driven by your own, personal taste. there are a lot of opinions and articles on this topic, even complete books were written.

I suggest the following:

[SMACSS](http://smacss.com/)
[OOCSS](http://oocss.org/)
[MVCSS](http://mvcss.github.io/styleguide/naming/)

All of them are mentioning a more-or-less similiar naming convention for CSS, while also saying that these are just rules of thumb, not dogmas.

personally, i follow that approach:

```
.modName // module

.modName__sub // an object or sub-module

.modName__sub--modifier // a modifier
```

A similiar structure is used for example by InuitCSS

If you want to use classnames as unique identifiers, than just do it, there is nothing wrong about that. Further, it is future proof in case that you wish to use it as a "standard" class. However, i would shirk that hash for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your modules or widgets are for (wordpress?) but the methodology I choose to use when coding is this:

1: If it is DOM element that has a specific function that I know will only appear once on the page, then I use an ID (things like #main_navigation, #global_header).

2: The DOM element is used for styling purposes (CSS) then I use class names. I keep class names as descriptive of what the DOM element is doing as I can. I don't use vauge names like .blue_text (explained below).

3: I need to attach some sort of information to the DOM element that is kind of awkward and doesn't fit this scheme, then I use custom HTML data attributes. For example, if I create a backend for a site and a user can pick a background color for a div, instead of putting `.user_selected_background_color_class` as a class in the div I will instead write `data="user_selected_color"`. This is a kind of lame example, but I just built something where a user can select a bunch of images to be in gallery mode or slideshow mode and I used data attributes to determine how the container div should be styled.